# Ubuntu 12.04 does not recognise CD

Tags: 12.04, mount

```
~$ wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'MATSHITA' 'DVD-RAM UJ8B1AS'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I don't find access to CD.

Kindly let me know how to rip the CD.

When I try to mount, it gives error.

```
~$ mount /dev/sg1
can't find /dev/sg1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

Comment: You need to specify where to mount: `sudo mount /dev/sg1 /mnt/`

Answer (score 0):

If the CD is not showing up in the graphical user interface, then try mounting it via the terminal

```
sudo mount /dev/sg1
```

If that doesn't work, then my suggestion would be to update your fstab file. It's relatively complicated, so let me know if mounting the CD manually doesn't work, and I'll post a tutorial on editing your fstab file.

But if the cd DOES show up, you want to rip the cd, you'll need software to do so. I suggest you search for "CD rip, or CD ripping" in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried mounting it manually, it gave following error. can't find /dev/sg1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: Hi Could you please post the tutorial on editing fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command:

```
ls -alhrt /dev/* | tail -n 30
```

looking date-wise, you can get the result of name of the usb devices. For me, following output was produced:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:2 -> ../ram2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 1:14 -> ../ram14
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 7:0 -> ../loop0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:3 -> ../ram3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 1:15 -> ../ram15
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 7:2 -> ../loop2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 1:11 -> ../ram11
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 1:10 -> ../ram10
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 7:5 -> ../loop5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:8 -> ../ram8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:9 -> ../ram9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:7 -> ../ram7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:5 -> ../ram5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 7:4 -> ../loop4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:4 -> ../ram4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 1:6 -> ../ram6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 7:7 -> ../loop7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Apr 29 03:26 7:6 -> ../loop6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Apr 29 03:26 8:0 -> ../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:9 -> ../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:2 -> ../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:4 -> ../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:6 -> ../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:3 -> ../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:7 -> ../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:8 -> ../sda8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:5 -> ../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Apr 29 03:26 8:1 -> ../sda1
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4.2K Apr 29 03:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  720 Apr 29  2012 .
```

from there, get the name of the usb device, let's for the time sake call it "usbdev".
Then enter the following command to mount it.

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/usbdev /media/USB_Bkup
```

Comment: Still i could not guess why wodim could not list the device? same error i got with fdisk -l

Comment: I tried this. Had no clue to figure out which one  in the list  is cdrom.`
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 May  1 13:35 7:63 -> ../vcs63
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 May  1 13:35 7:191 -> ../vcsa63
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 3.8K May  1 13:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4.2K May  1 16:32 ..
sudo mount /dev/vcs63 /media/cdrom
mount: /dev/vcs63 is not a block device
`

Comment: for list all the devices you are getting threw fdisk-l. Then just check the entry here and find out if any new device is listed here. If so, it will be your cd-rom device.

Comment: I tried fdisk -l . it does not list out anything. i.e. output is empty.

Comment: are you sure you are running fdisk command as root.If you are not then it will not list anything. Well, try entering command as `sudo fidsk-l'

Comment: Output of sudo fdisk -l
/dev/sda1 , /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3 /dev/sda5 /dev/sda6       /dev/sda7

Answer (score 0):

In a shell (Crtl-Alt-T to open one) type:

```
sudo lshw -C disk
```

This should show you all disk devices including DVD/CDROM drives. They will be noted with their logical names included. lshw should be installed but `sudo apt-get install lshw` will install it if it is not.